# Use half-duplex or full-duplex RS-485?

Tags: serial, rs485

I have a master microcontroller that can control 4 slave microcontrollers. Each slave microcontroller is connected to 3 sensors.

The master microcontroller asks to retrieve the value of a specific sensor on a specific slave, and the slave sends the value to the master. And so on...

Can I use the full duplex protocol? Like this (where RO = RX and DI = TX) :

[image]

Is it better to use half-duplex ? When is it necessary to use half-duplex ? It implies enabling receive and driver at a specific timing which can be annoying compared to the full duplex method.

I have never used an RS-485 before so I am a beginner :)

Comment: "Full duplex RS-485" (a misnomer) is really called RS-422.

Comment: Sure full-duplex is fine, if you are creating this for personal/proprietary use. Are you aiming for compatibility with other RS-422/485 devices? Because that quickly gets *much* harder.

Comment: Do you have 2 lines for comms? Then half duplex - the master sends, disables its transmitter so it can listen, the slave enables its transmitter and responds then disables its transmitter so it can listen.  Do you have 4 lines? Then full duplex can be supported - the master sends, and the slave can start responding while the master can continue to send. Slave disables its transmitter after sending so other slaves can transmit if needed.

Comment: I read that RS-422 is not quite the same as full duplex RS-485 : it is point-to-point communication and can control 10 slaves only.
What do you mean by compatibility ? I intend to use the same RS-422/485 reference for the 5 microcontrollers. Then it would be UART between the RS-422/485 and the microcontroller. Is that fine ?

Comment: @CrossRoads can I use full duplex without having to care for disabling the slave transmitters given that only one slave can respond at a time ? The aim is to be as simple as possible. :)

Comment: No, you need to have the slave not be driving their transmit line high or low when not transmitting.  https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/ANDI/ANDIS20354/ANDIS20354-1.pdf?hkey=EC6BD57738AE6E33B588C5F9AD3CEFA7  "The most significant differentiator of the RS-485 standard is that the drivers can be disabled, thereby allowing more than one to be connected to a single line. Only one driver should be
enabled at a time"  "Only one driver can transmit at a particular time, but
multiple receivers can be enabled simultaneously. "  If 1 slave transmits, 1 sits high, 2 sit low? Junk rcv'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it better to use half-duplex ? When is it necessary to use
>   half-duplex ? It implies enabling receive and driver at a specific
>   timing which can be annoying compared to the full duplex method.

It is necessary to use full-duplex when you want to transmit and receive simultaneously.

It has nothing to do with the number of slave nodes, which requires either moderation/collision avoidance mechanism on one bus or individual peer-to-peer connections between master and each slave.

It is never "necessary" to use half-duplex. The "better" part is defined mostly by the number of wires you are willing to run between the nodes.

The "annoying" part is highly exaggerated. Since in your code

> ... master microcontroller asks to retrieve the value of a specific sensor
>   on a specific slave, and the slave sends the value to the master ...

you already have these two separate transmit/receive states. Adding one GPIO switch in between is trivial.

Another consequence of the method of operation quoted above is that you also have moderation mechanism defined. If slave can only respond after being prompted and only one can be prompted at a time then there is no risk of collision (unless you mess up slave address assignment, that is).

If you sum up all of the above you'd see that half-duplex communication with all the nodes on a same bus is quite sufficient for your needs. You just have to make sure that you use RS-485 compatible transceivers, like ADM3485.

Answer (score 0):

How many ports do you have on each side?  If you have two ports on each device, then it's easiest to just use one for each direction.  If you have devices with only one port, you can still talk bidirectionally, but you have to take more care in timing and arbitration to avoid conflicts.

If you wanted to avoid all chance of conflict, you'd need 8 ports on your controller, 2 for each slave.  This seems like overkill, though, since your environment is polled anyway.  Without a complete understanding of your requirements, it's hard for us to make that tradeoff for you.